# transform to conditionally mask elements and attributes from input

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

My output xml should be masked with some elements, based on a variable, flag.If the flag has a value of '1', the output xml should have only the element 'a'(include all its attributes and child elements). If the flag is 2, output xml should have elements a and b. If it is 3, all the elements and attributes present in the input should be present in the output

my input xml

```
<Root>

<a ref="t">
<s id="2">value</s>
</a>
<b ref="t">
<s id="2">value</s>
</b>
<c ref="t">
<s id="2">value</s>
</c>
</Root>
```

my desired output(when flag is 1)

```
<Root>

<a ref="t">
<s id="2">value</s>
</a>
</Root>
```

xslt i tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="flag" select="'1'"/>


<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">

<xsl:copy>

<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>

</xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:if test ="$flag ='1'">
<xsl:template match="b"></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="c"></xsl:template>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below xslt is working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="flag" select="'1'"/>


<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">

<xsl:copy>

<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>

</xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="b">
<xsl:if test="$flag ='3' or $flag='2'">
  <xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
<xsl:if test="$flag ='3'">
  <xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```